# Preparing http request url in interceptors in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I tried to prepare http request url in interceptors rather than adding it to the object passed in $http. Here is the sample of code I tried:

```
angular.module('myapp', [])

.service('myservice', function() {
    this.myfunction = function() {
        var req = {method: 'POST', reqName: 'getInfo'};
        return $http(req);
    }
})

.factory('myInterceptor', function() {
    var interceptor = {
        'request': function(config) {
            config.url = "http://www.myapi.com/demo/"+config.reqName;
            return config;
        }
    }
    return interceptor;
})

.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptor');
})
```

But I'm getting an error, which says:

> Error: [$http:badreq] Http request configuration url must be a string.
>
> Received: undefined

Any help?

Comment: Please read https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors then return config object from `myInterceptor` factory

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski can you please explain it briefly (if you found a solution).

Comment: factory **should** returns variable `interceptor`. Adding statement `return interceptor` in `myInterceptor` will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @KrzysztofSafjanowski for the improvement, but this was not the thing which was causing the error. Same error persist even after the changes.

Comment: you have miss to add **$http** as dependency to **myservice** service

Answer (score 0):

Let me show some tests that proof AngularJS documentation is correct.

Some details about **Interceptor** - http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .service('service', function($http) {
    this.myfunction = function() {
      var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        reqName: 'getInfo'
      };
      return $http(req);
    }
  })
  .factory('myInterceptor', function() {
    var interceptor = {
      'request': function(config) {
        config.url = "http://www.myapi.com/demo/" + config.reqName;
        return config;
      }
    }
    return interceptor;
  })
  .config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptor');
  })


describe("myApp", function() {
  beforeEach(module("myApp"));

  it("executes intercpetor that changes request", inject(function(service, $httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.expectPOST("http://www.myapi.com/demo/getInfo").respond(201, []);

    service.myfunction().then(function(r) {
      expect(r.config.url).toBe('http://www.myapi.com/demo/getInfo')
    })

    $httpBackend.flush();
  }));
});
```

```html
<link href="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine-2.0.3-concated.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please find any difference between documentation and my answer and your code

Comment: Sorry, but it didn''t work for me. I would be great if you can share a fiddle.

Comment: @PratikKulshreshth if you know any public API that I can query - I'm open to create JSFiddle to proof it